# type mismatch with Peekable of Iterator trait object

Tags: rust

This code compiles fine:

```rust
use std::iter::Peekable;

struct Token {
    length: u32,
}

fn get_tokens() -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Token>> {
    todo!()
}

fn do_something_with_boxed_filter(boxed: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Token>>) {}

fn main() {
    let tokens = get_tokens();
    let long_tokens = tokens.filter(|token| token.length > 32);
    let boxed = Box::new(long_tokens);
    do_something_with_boxed_filter(boxed);
}
```

But if I try to make a peekable version, as shown below, it fails to compile.

```rust
use std::iter::Peekable;

struct Token {
    length: u32,
}

fn get_tokens() -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Token>> {
    todo!()
}

fn do_something_with_peekable(peekable: Peekable<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Token>>>) {}

fn main() {
    let tokens = get_tokens();
    let long_tokens = tokens.filter(|token| token.length > 32);
    let boxed = Box::new(long_tokens);
    let peekable = boxed.peekable();
    do_something_with_peekable(peekable);
}
```

The error message is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:18:32
   |
15 |     let long_tokens = tokens.filter(|token| token.length > 32);
   |                                     ------------------------- the found closure
...
18 |     do_something_with_peekable(peekable);
   |                                ^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn Iterator`, found struct `Filter`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Peekable<Box<(dyn Iterator<Item = Token> + 'static)>>`
              found struct `Peekable<Box<Filter<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Token>>, [closure@src/main.rs:15:37: 15:62]>>>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

I don't understand this; the `Filter` struct implements `Iterator` so shouldn't I be able to use a `Filter` struct in place of the `dyn Iterator` trait object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right with all the things you said.

The problem is that you can only feed things into functions that can be coerced.

`Box<T>` is coercible to `Box<dyn Trait>` if `T: Trait`. However, at the time of writing, this goes only one level deep. `Peekable<Box<T>>` can **not** be coerced into `Peekable<Box<dyn Trait>>`. Therefore, you need to force the coercion *before* creating the `Peekable`:

```rust
use std::iter::Peekable;

struct Token {
    length: u32,
}

fn get_tokens() -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Token>> {
    todo!()
}

fn do_something_with_peekable(peekable: Peekable<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Token>>>) {}

fn main() {
    let tokens = get_tokens();
    let long_tokens = tokens.filter(|token| token.length > 32);
    let boxed = Box::new(long_tokens) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Token>>;
    let peekable = boxed.peekable();
    do_something_with_peekable(peekable);
}
```

---

An alternative would be to use the `impl` keyword:

```rust
use std::iter::Peekable;

struct Token {
    length: u32,
}

fn get_tokens() -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Token>> {
    todo!()
}

fn do_something_with_peekable(peekable: Peekable<Box<impl Iterator<Item = Token>>>) {}

fn main() {
    let tokens = get_tokens();
    let long_tokens = tokens.filter(|token| token.length > 32);
    let boxed = Box::new(long_tokens);
    let peekable = boxed.peekable();
    do_something_with_peekable(peekable);
}
```

With `impl`, *no coercion happens*. `Box<dyn Trait>` is a Box to an unsized trait type, where `Box<impl Trait>` is actually a real type that implements the `Trait`. The information what type it is does not get lost to the compiler, `impl Trait` is actually syntactic sugar for intruducing a generic `Box<T> where T: Trait`.

`impl` has advantages and disadvantages. The biggest disadvantage is that just like normal generics, it compiles a new version of the function for every type that gets used with it (I think).

The advantage is that there is no longer the need for a `Box` at all:

```rust
use std::iter::Peekable;

struct Token {
    length: u32,
}

fn get_tokens() -> impl Iterator<Item = Token> {
    vec![].into_iter()
}

fn do_something_with_peekable(peekable: Peekable<impl Iterator<Item = Token>>) {}

fn main() {
    let tokens = get_tokens();
    let long_tokens = tokens.filter(|token| token.length > 32);
    let peekable = long_tokens.peekable();
    do_something_with_peekable(peekable);
}
```

Just be aware that the types of two objects of `Peekable<dyn Trait>` are always identical, while the type of two `Peekable<impl Trait>` objects could be different. `Peekable<dyn Trait>` *is* a type, while `Peekable<impl Trait>` is *not* a type, it's more of a placeholder for a type. Therefore, you cannot store different objects of `Peekable<impl Trait>` in one vector, because the vector wouldn't know which type to choose.

Comment: At the time of writing and forever. Going further is fundamentally impossible, at least in the general case.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman would you be able to elaborate on why that is impossible?

Comment: @dipea Take for a example a case like `Box<Box<T>>` to `Box<Box<dyn Trait>`. `Box<T>` is a thin pointer, one-`usize` wide, while `Box<dyn Trait>` is twice as thick. Converting `Box<T>` to `Box<dyn Trait>` will require allocating 2-`usize` `Box`, copying the pointer + adding the vtable, and releasing the original `Box`. Allocation in the compiler, automatically, is a no-go for Rust (although it is possible for GCed languages, it is too hard for system languages: for example, what with `Rc`? Will the compiler know about it too)?